# Using an interface to save only required data from a response

Tags: angular, angular7

A server response is returning me a lot of unnecessary data and I created an interface to get only the necessary items but I don't know how to do it

My Interface

```
export interface UsersInfo{
  id: string;
  name: string;
  street: string;
}
```

My return from API

```
return this.http.get<any[]>(url, {params, headers})
  .pipe(map((res: any) => {
      return res.items;
    }));
```

JSON looks like this

```
{
  'id' : 'A457BS',
   [...]
  'info'{
     name: 'John',
     street: '5',
     [...]
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
return this.http.get< VideosYoutube[]>(url, {params, headers})
.pipe(map((res: VideosYoutube[]) => {
    return res.items.map((item) => {
       var {id, name, street} = res;
       return {id, name, street};
    } 
}));
```

We should pass the type of response we want in the http.get method but this won't remove the unused properties. To get only what we want we can destructure from the api response and create a local map.

Answer (score 0):

Use `Array.prototype.map()` on the response body, like so, to mutate the data in each element and get an array of the mutated data:

```
return this.http.get<any[]>(url, {params, headers})
  .pipe(map((res: any) => {
      return res.items.map((item) => {
        return {
          id: item.id,
          name: item.info.name,
          street: item.info.street,
        } as VideosYoutube;
      });
    }));
```